# History of 10 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Comment: Duplicate: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4590/10-of-the-month-of-teves

Comment: As I am running a series it would of been nice of the fellow to not ask that question and make me a duplicate.

Comment: I changed the question to adress that you history me why we fast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Nebuchadnezzar laid siege to Yerushalayim

2)3,000 Jews were killed in Riots in Bucharest riots in !941

3)There was a Decree of the Elimination of Jews from German Economic Life in 1939.

4) The Nazis in Warsaw issued a decreed that Jews where not to greet Germans in public in 1939.

5)The graves Of Yehoshua Bin Nun & Kalev Ben Yefuneh Desecrated by Arabs in 2010

6)Yahrtzeits

-Zecharia Hanavi

-Malachi (Medrash says same as Ezra Hasofer)

-Harav Nosson of Breslov Mechaber of Likutie Halachos in 1844

-Rav Yehuda Eileinberg Mechaber of Minchas Yitchok 1610

-The Rabbanut of Israel Declared Asara B'Teves as Yom ha-Kaddish ha-Klali which means the general Memorial Day for those Jews who died during the Holocaust whose Yahrzeit is  not known

Answer (score 3):

10th Teves is most notorious for the siege that Nebuchadnezzar laid to Jerusalem (in 425 BCE). Although it took 30 months for Jerusalem to fall and the Temple to be destroyed (on Tisha B'Av), this day carries the dubious distinction of being the "beginning of the end" of the First Temple era.

Here are some interesting articles on this date: http://tinyurl.com/10-Teves